# Can you send notification between Android Emulator device and USB connected real device in Android Studio for demonstration purpose with database?

Tags: android, android-database, usb-debugging, android-usb

I want to make an app that has two accounts and mutual database. I want to send notification from the first to the second account in real time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an external database such as Firebase. Regardless of what phone you do it on, you can access the information and insert data onto it. You can use [this documentation] (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) for more information on it but also check the Stack Overflow website

Answer (score 0):

You must use the database
There are several databases available for this. 
If you are familiar with MySQL, you can take a look at this [how to connect android with php mysql](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/), otherwise, this [firebase database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) can help you.